why imported function gets access to document variable in javascript?
//a.js
    let func1=function(){
        console.log(p);
    }
    export default export func1;

//index.js
    import func1 from "./a.js";
    let p=1000;
    func1(); 

shows error p is undefined. But if a.js is like this
//a.js
    let func1=function(){
        document.querySelector(".img1").addEventListener("click",()=>{console.log(12)})
    }
    export default export func1;

imported func1 gets access to document variable when the script file a.js has nothing to do with document and click listener logs 12 on a click. Can you explain why?

OK, so this is a different question from your previous one. But still - all functions in the browser get access to the browser API. Yet again, nothing to do with importing. It's always worked that way.

Yeah, document is just part of the environment the code is executing in. Same for window, console etc.

In Javascript, variables have "lexical scope", but there is also one global object, which always has global scope.
document is the same as window.document, and is provided by the browser. window is the global object when Javascript is executed in the browser.
You can always access the global object and it's direct properties from everywhere. When the Javascript code is executed in a different environment (e.g. node, i.e. not a browser), then there may be a different global object, with different properties (i.e. no window and no document).
The imported function has access to document, because document is a property of the global object window, and therefore is automatically defined in the global scope.
Your p variable on the other hand is defined in the lexical environment of the module, so it can only be accessed inside that module.
You could access p in the same way as document, if you would add a property to the window object: window.p = 1000 (But you should generally not define such "global properties".)
